# RestartResource doesn't prompt when run from bundle

Tags: wix, wix3.10

I have a bundle which chains an MSI, using the MsiPackage element. In that MSI I have added the following:

```
<util:RestartResource Path="[VS2015DEVENV]" />
```

When I just execute the MSI, with VS running I get a prompt to close VS as expected. However when I run the Bundle, I don't get a prompt. Is there some configuration I have to set on the bundle to allow those prompts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `ShowFilesInUse` option to the `WixStandardBootstrapperApplication` solved this.

```
...
<bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
    ...
    ShowFilesInUse="yes"/>
...
```